# ClickOnce signer's certificate not valid for signing when using makecert/pvk2pfx

Tags: .net, clickonce

All of a sudden my **unexpired** certificate created using makecert/pvk2pfx is throwing an error when attempting to publish a ClickOnce application. This worked fine just last week...

Error Message:

> Error    2    An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign
>   bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: The signer's
>   certificate is not valid for signing. SignTool Error: An error
>   occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

When I use the "Create Test Certificate" option in the Signing tab that certificate works fine and the application is published successfully.

When manually creating my certificate with makecert/pvk2pfx I'm following the [MSDN instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx).

When I delete my old manually created certificate, create a new one using makecert/pvk2pfx and try to use that one I get the same error.

The application is a WPF application targeting .NET 4, and this is all in Visual Studio 2010...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It worked for me after I specified the certificate length greater than 1024:

```
makecert -sv MyApp.pvk -n "CN=MyCompany" -len 2048 MyApp.cer -r
pvk2pfx -pvk MyApp.pvk -spc MyApp.cer -pfx MyApp.pfx -po MyPassword
```

Microsoft released an update that affects all certificates having an RSA key less than 1024 bits long.

*[Microsoft Security Advisory: Update for minimum certificate key length](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661254)*

Comment: Yes, that was the underlying problem. I think that the -len switch is not necessary though because after the update makecert creates certificates with length greater than 1024 by default.

Comment: My certificate was invalid so I tried -len 2048 and it was still invalid. The actual problem was solved by adding the **-r** which then removed the signtool error.

Comment: The `-r` part is crucial. More recent versions of makecert will use a default of 2048 bits so the -len part is not necessary.

Answer (score 8):

After using the `-r` switch (create a self signed certificate) with Makecert, the pfx certificate generated with pvk2pfx now works for ClickOnce publishing... I am not sure exactly what happened here since the old key that was not "self signed" worked fine for a long time...

Exact commands I used to create the working pfx certificate...

```
makecert -sv MyApp.pvk -n "CN=MyCompany" MyApp.cer -r

pvk2pfx -pvk MyApp.pvk -spc MyApp.cer -pfx MyApp.pfx
```

Comment: Yes, the `-r` is crucial. I tried to move a certificate to Windows 10, but I had to recreate it and had to use `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Visual Studio 2013 project that I could sign with a (Visual Studio-generated) pfx file, but that same certificate would not work using the *SignTool*, no matter what I did.

I then started making new certs using *MakeCert* and *Pvk2Pfx*, and that didn't work either. I tried changing the encryption from SHA1 to SHA512, changing the key length from 256 to 2048 (as suggested elsewhere), changing the version of *SignTool*, etc, etc.

I must have checked 1,000 different links containing "The Signer's Certificate Is Not Valid For Signing".

I'm summarizing the main things that will most likely fix the problem. This is all based on generating a new pfx file; the Visual Studio-generated one won't be usable.

1. Generate your `.cer` and `.pvk` files using *MakeCert* with the `-len` switch set to at least 1024 - or, better for future-proofing, 2048 - and the all-important `-r` switch which self-signs the certificate. I explicitly added an end date (using `-e 12/31/2039`) and SH256 encryption algorithm (`-a SHA256`). I suggest adding a password.
2. Generate your `.pfx` file from the `.cer` and `.pvk` files using *Pvk2Pfx* with the standard/default switches.
3. Use *SignTool* to sign the assembly, using `-p {YourPassword}` matching the *MakeCert*-provided password.