# ClickOnce certificates no longer work, but not expired

Tags: clickonce, signing, pfx

I've been using the same system for creating long-term certificates from a VS.NET 2008/2010 command prompt for several years.  However, as of this morning (and possibly earlier), all of my publish attempts fail.

I've been using (*basically*) this batch file to generate PFX files for years:

```
@echo PFX key creation utility: Usage:
@echo CreatePFX.bat [key name]
@echo THIS MUST BE RUN FROM A VS.NET 2010 COMMAND PROMPT
makecert.exe -sv %1.pvk -n "CN=MY KEY" %1.cer
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk %1.pvk -spc %1.cer -pfx %1.pfx
del %1.pvk
del %1.cer
```

These certificates do not expire until 2039.  They've worked for years now, but are suddenly failing when I click "Publish" with the error:

> An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign
>   bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: The signer's
>   certificate is not valid for signing. SignTool Error: An error
>   occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe

This error is generally attributed to expired keys, which is not the case here.  Has anyone else seen this occur with an active, locally created PFX key?

Answer (score 1):

Wow---looks like I'm not the first to see this:

I had the exact same experience...adding the "-r" switch did the trick, but I'm uncertain why it just because an issue.

[ClickOnce signer's certificate not valid for signing when using makecer/pvk2pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844868/clickonce-signers-certificate-not-valid-for-signing-when-using-makecer-pvk2pfx)