# Makecert.exe error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clickonce, digital-certificate, makecert

I am trying to use Makecert.exe to create a signing certificate that I can use with our internal VS.NET applications, to be deployed using *Clickonce* on our local network

I have been following the MSDN guide [MSDN: Certificate Expiration in ClickOnce Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx)

so I tried the below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>Makecert -sv DMTeam.pvk 
-n "CN=DMTeam" DMTeam.cer -b 03/04/2015 -e 12/31/2020
```

in order to have a certificate for our applications

When I run the above command using the VS command prompt, I get the below error:

> Error: Unable to create file for the subject ('DMTeam.pvk')
>
> Error: Can't create the key of the subject ('DMTeam.pvk')
>
> Failed

so what am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running in an elevated command shell? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278381 may be relevant here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is to run the command prompt with Administrator privileges.

I did something very similar, though I wrote the pvk and cer files to my c:\Temp folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin>MakeCert –sv C:\Temp\DMTeam.pvk –n “CN=DMTeam” c:\Temp\DMTeam.cer –b 03/04/2015 –e 12/31/2020 -r

Don't forget the "-r" option as it will "Create a self-signed certificate"! Without it the project will not build when you use the created pfx file.

I ran this under the VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt (with Run as Administrator) and it works just fine.  Run without Administrative privileges and then it fails.

Then to create the pfx file do the following:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin>pvk2pfx –pvk C:\Temp\DMTeam.pvk –spc C:\Temp\DMTeam.cer –pfx –po PasswordForPFXFile

Here are some good references:
See section: Test Certificates, MakeCert, RenewCert, and The Big Workaround
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.110).aspx

[ClickOnce signer's certificate not valid for signing when using makecer/pvk2pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844868/clickonce-signers-certificate-not-valid-for-signing-when-using-makecer-pvk2pfx?rq=1)

My ClickOnce app now builds fine in Visual Studio 2013.